# While printing a div using window.print(), the margins in @page{ } are not getting applied

Tags: html, css, css-paged-media

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('Invoice')" value="print a div!"/>
<div id="Invoice">
<!-- Some Content-->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<head><style type="text/css" media="print">

@page{
    margin-right : 0;
    margin-left : 0;
    margin-top : 1in;
    margin-bottom :1in;
}

</style>
</head>
```

When I click on the button print preview opens up but margin is not applied.

Comment: Could you also supply the JavaScript code?

Comment: I have just tested this with `@page { margin: 1em 0; }` on Google Chrome and it worked for me... I selected the "Background graphics" option.

Comment: @Carty the margins under the printer settings are selected to default every time i click on the button.

Comment: Add this to your style tag: `html, body {background: #000; color: #fff;}` and see if you can see any visible margins. It might be that they are there but you cannot see them because of the white elements on white background...

Comment: no visible margins @carty